# I cannot see a Ubuntu PC in my windows 10 network

Tags: networking, samba

I have a PC called 'Windows' and it runs W10 home. I installed Ubuntu and **samba** on PC 'Ubuntu' and created a **shared map**.

- I can ping in both directions.
- I see PC 'Ubuntu' from PC 'Windows' with **nbtstat** and both have the same workgroup name.

But I do not see PC 'Ubuntu' in my PC 'Windows' network map, **even after stopping the firewall** on 'Windows'.

On 'Ubuntu' PC  I have **not installed a firewall** yet.

My purpose is to work on PC 'Ubuntu' files from PC 'Windows'.
Any idea's on how to proceed?

Comment: well I don't quite understand because your explanation was confusing but folder sharing is supposed to come from ubuntu and windows will be able to see that with samba. the remote drive isn't supposed to show up under network locations. it's not detectable by windows. And samba points arent listed there. In the left-side list of locations find "This PC", right-click on it and select "Connect a network Drive" that's the correct way to do it.

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/share-folders-local-network-ubuntu-windows/

Comment: @tatsu. I have tried this and this functions OK. Many Thanks! I need to edit the windows registry of that PC 'A'. Is it with the same computer name \\ubuntu and will I be possible to remove some keys of bad drivers?

Comment: I don't think so. windows will probably refuse exterior root privilege going trhough samba. Samba is the wrong tool to be doing this sort of thing. ssh might be the way: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server by the way this counts as a seperate question. I'll put the answer I gave above as an official answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you follow the instructions here : https://itsfoss.com/share-folders-local-network-ubuntu-windows/
[image: share folder right-click menu]
[image: tick share]
[image: finalise share]

the folder should now be visible from windows.